# apache virtualhost with ssl not working on subdirectories

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have an issue with my virtual host SSL configuration. 
My site works on the basic domain www.my_domain.com for both HTTP and HTTPS but doesn't work on all the subdirectories.
Example:

- http://www.my_domain.com - works
- https://www.my_domain.com - works
- http://www.my_domain.com/secondary - works
- https://www.my_domain.com/secondary - doesn't work

My virtual host setup is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin my_domain@gmail.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 ServerName www.my_domain.com
 ServerAlias my_domain.com
 ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log

 Alias /secondary /var/www/html/secondary/
 <Directory /var/www/html/secondary/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    allow from all
    order allow,deny
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My ssl.conf setup is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.my_domain.com:443
...
SSLEngine on
SLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite DEFAULT:!EXP:!SSLv2:!DES:!IDEA:!SEED:+3DES
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The error is: The requested URL /secondary was not found on this server.

Comment: Your SSL VirtualHost does not define a DocumentRoot, so it does not know where to look for /secondary.  /secondary is only defined in your HTTP (port 80) VirtualHost.  You have to put all the configuration in both if you want both to return the same content.  You could configure your HTTP VirtualHost to redirect 301 to HTTPS all the time and always respond via SSL too.

Comment: Thank you! Actually putting all the configuration in both everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it solved the OP`s problem, here is my comment as an answer.

Your SSL VirtualHost does not define a DocumentRoot, so it does not know where to look for /secondary. /secondary is only defined in your HTTP (port 80) VirtualHost. You have to put all the configuration in both if you want both to return the same content.